# Measuring distance between centroids R

Tags: r, distance

I want to create a matrix of the distance (in metres) between the centroids of every country in the world. Country names or country IDs should be included in the matrix.

The matrix is based on a shapefile of the world downloaded here: http://gadm.org/version2

Here is some rough info on the shapefile I'm using (I'm using shapefile@data$UN as my ID):

```
> str(shapefile@data)
'data.frame':   174 obs. of  11 variables:
$ FIPS     : Factor w/ 243 levels "AA","AC","AE",..: 5 6 7 8 10 12 13 
$ ISO2     : Factor w/ 246 levels "AD","AE","AF",..: 61 17 6 7 9 11 14   
$ ISO3     : Factor w/ 246 levels "ABW","AFG","AGO",..: 64 18 6 11 3 10 
$ UN       : int  12 31 8 51 24 32 36 48 50 84 ...
$ NAME     : Factor w/ 246 levels "Afghanistan",..: 3 15 2 11 6 10 13 
$ AREA     : int  238174 8260 2740 2820 124670 273669 768230 71 13017 
$ POP2005  : int  32854159 8352021 3153731 3017661 16095214 38747148 
$ REGION   : int  2 142 150 142 2 19 9 142 142 19 ...
$ SUBREGION: int  15 145 39 145 17 5 53 145 34 13 ...
$ LON      : num  2.63 47.4 20.07 44.56 17.54 ...
$ LAT      : num  28.2 40.4 41.1 40.5 -12.3 ...
```

I tried this:

```
library(rgeos)
shapefile <- readOGR("./Map/Shapefiles/World/World Map", layer = "TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3") # Read in world shapefile

row.names(shapefile) <- as.character(shapefile@data$UN)
centroids <- gCentroid(shapefile, byid = TRUE, id = as.character(shapefile@data$UN)) # create centroids

dist_matrix <- as.data.frame(geosphere::distm(centroids))
```

The result looks something like this:

```
    V1         V2         V3         V4
1   0.0        4296620.6  2145659.7  4077948.2
2   4296620.6  0.0        2309537.4  219442.4
3   2145659.7  2309537.4  0.0        2094277.3
4   4077948.2  219442.4   2094277.3  0.0
```

1) Instead of the first column (1,2,3,4) and row (V1, V2, V3, V4) I would like to have country IDs (shapefile@data$UN) or names (shapefile@data@NAME). How does that work?

2) I'm not sure of the value that is returned. Is it metres, kilometres, etc?

3) Is geosphere::distm preferable to geosphere:distGeo in this instance?

Comment: Part 1 is easy... you just want to use `colnames(dist_matrix) <- shapefile@data$UN`, and repeat with `rownames()`. For part 2... after you have the names, it should be pretty easy to figure out. 3) Check your results and if they are right you're set, if they're wrong, then try other function?

Comment: The  geosphere::distm documentation  says "Distance value in the same units as parameter a of the ellipsoid (default is meters)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1.

This should work to add the column and row names to your matrix. Just as you had done when adding the row names to `shapefile`

```
crnames<-as.character(shapefile@data$UN)
colnames(dist_matrix)<- crnames
rownames(dist_matrix)<- crnames
```

### 2.

The default distance function in `distm` is `distHaversine`, which takes a radius( of the earth) variable in m. So I assume the output is in m.

### 3.

Look at the documentation for `distGeo` and `distHaversine` and decide the level of accuracy you want in your results. To look at the docs in R itself just enter `?distGeo`.

edit: answer to q1 may be wrong since the matrix data may be aggregated, looking at alternatives